# Trying to develop a rather specific class loading system with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Before I say anything I want to thank the dev for taking the time to do documentation for Byte Buddy. I know how tedious that can be, and I appreciate it.

However I am still having a bit of trouble with the conversion I am doing. I did a lot of searching but there is not a lot out there.

Currently I use javassist. The system works, but it just lacks in some areas and creates a high amount of overhead. I think byte buddy could be the solution. However the project I am working on must be runtime code converted. It needs to remain stable in the live environment so a hot swapper is not what I am looking for (however I do find that great to use the same system for the test environment).

The issue is I need to grab classes at certain times, and load several, so that I can inject my plugins at the proper moments during the load process.

In javassist, (note this is only the VERY beginning) it starts out like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        initLogger();

        Loader loader = HookManager.getInstance().getLoader();
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("javafx.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("com.sun.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("org.controlsfx.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("impl.org.controlsfx");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("com.mysql.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("org.sqlite.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("com.xyp.modloader.classhooks.");
        loader.delegateLoadingOf("javassist.");

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);

        loader.run("net.xyp.modloader.DelegatedLauncher", args);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerLauncher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
```

The code then continues on into other classes within the plugin injection system. Which calls more classes and at the right moments fires methods within the injection system that calls the plugins that need to be inserted at those moments.

Example 2 classes into the system this method gets called public void

```
public void fireOnServerStarted() {
    ModComm.serverStarted();
    serverStarted.fire(listener -> listener.onServerStarted());
}
```

When that fires the system has interfaces that the plugins target, telling the system it is the right moment to inject those plugins. This happens on several different states, and it is very important they fire at the right times. For some reason I am just not grasping how to do this with Byte Buddy, and I think it is because all of the examples are just a single method or field being loaded.

I mulled over deleting this post because someone may have a solution I have not come across. However at this time and doing more research I feel that Byte Buddy doesn't include the most important capability that I use from Javassist to do what I was trying to convert. Willing to hear alternatives!

Comment: For all (advanced) (byte)code generation tasks, i consider it a good approach to first write a working version of the soon to be generated classes. That way you have a verification that what you want actually can be done, and a testcase for your generation. Your description is quite fuzzy on the details on what you want to create. So write a minimal version of that plugin mechanism, add it to your question and maybe you will get some answers how to dynamically generate it.

Comment: I have more than a minimal version complete already, but it uses Javassist and the overhead is starting to get really high. I reached out to the Byte Buddy dev with a willingness to pay for an afternoon get familiar lesson.

Comment: At this time however I think one of the most important key features of Javassist which I use a lot is not possible at all with Byte Buddy. So I am looking into other solutions. I really appreciate your thoughts however and thank you for the time to try and get clarification.

Comment: Please go over your question and consider deleting all parts that do not contribute to the real topic. There might be a nice question - but it is buried in many lines of you talking about things that don't matter in the context of your problem.

Comment: Example - if you like byte buddy documentation then send a mail to the author of the tool. But this praise does not help with understanding your problem. So please get rid of it.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. It isn't so much praise, and the documentation isn't all that. The benchmarks is what drew me to it. Javassist was great at first but as the project has grown so has the overhead costs. Just seeking a better way.

To address your critisism, and thank you for that, The things I am missing is how to use Byte Buddy's class loaders to pinpoint when I want to fire off the loading of my new classes or edits, and I use the expression editors and .insertAfter/.insertBefore ALOT which Byte Buddy offers no way to alter the body of a method. It is throw it away or keep it.

Comment: I sort of see your concern, but my attempt ws to pinpoint a singular problem. I found more later, I was trying to keep the issue narrow. I need to control when the class loader loads which class. It can't really be generic or defined for me, until all my module getting hooks are fired off, which has to happen at specific times. If you would like you are welcome to edit my question, and add some comments, then I will go over it and see if I can fix it up. I have been working with this system for 2 years so it just makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirly sure if I understand your question but from what I understand, you are trying to delegate to several class loaders as a parent class loader?

Byte Buddy offers the `MultipleParentClassLoader` for such purposes. The example code you posted does not include Javassist code, therefore I cannot give you more specific advice.